# How to prompt a text in stylegan2

Tags: image, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, generative-adversarial-network, stylegan

I would like to input a text prompt in [stylegan2](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2).

So far, I've been able to load the generator (G) using

```
G,D,Gs = load_networks('gdrive:networks/stylegan2-ffhq-config-a.pkl')
```

which calls a function defined in the `pretrained_networks.py` file.

Now, I can't figure out how to use the generator in the way I would like.

Specifically, given a text prompt, I suppose I should:

1. to encode the text in a numpy array
2. to feed the generator with this encoding

but how can I do it?

Comment: What makes you think StyleGAN takes text prompts?

Comment: @xdurch0 it's stylegan2 (I don't know if stylegan differs under this prospective). By the way, in more than one article I read they say they used stylegan2 as a text-to-image generator. For instance https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2205/2205.12512.pdf. But my concern is about the usage of a pre-trained stylegan2... I assume I should use the same text encoder they have used before the training.